# Ruby - how to geocode a 1000 of adresses?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps, google-api, google-geocoder

I have a database of approx. 1000 addresses, which I need to geocode. If I run the script for getting coordinations, I'll obviously get the **OVER_QUERY_LIMIT** error (I am using Google Geocoder).

What's the best way to obtain these coordinations?

Comment: This is against the terms of service of google maps - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/articles/usage_limits

Comment: The TOS says "[100,000 requests per 24 hour period.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/faq#usage_limits)" for most of the options. How will 1000 exceed 100,000?

Comment: Hey try to geocode your addresses in chuncks. Let's say 50 every 10 minutes or something like that.